# Is it possible to have multi-value field in Google App Engine Datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to have a GAE-Python Datastore Kind for something similar to a Blog and I would like to have a field for Categories or Tags where there can be multiple Tags for a given Blog instance.  I am a GAE/Python newbie and am trying to find a way to be able to assign multiple  categories for a single instance.

e.g.

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    category = db.CategoryProperty()
```

How would I modify this to enable multiple categories for a MyModel instance?

If this is possible, what would a query to retrieve the instances for a single category value look like?

What would a "put" with multiple values for this field look like?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or links to where I can find applicable documentation..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are starting now with this project consider NDB and [repeated property](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#repeated)

```
class MyModel(ndb.Model):
category = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`ListProperty`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#ListProperty) or a [`StringListProperty`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#StringListProperty) to store a list of categories; these store a list (or a list of strings) and you can use the property values just like you would normally use a list in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **TextProperty** to store any kind of values in list or in dict or in combination of list-dict or so..